# Inexplicable Apache 403

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two documents in my root directory.  One is served up fine, the other always returns a 403.

Here's the output from the access_log:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [22/Nov/2012:09:53:21 -0500] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [22/Nov/2012:09:53:22 -0500] "GET /sales.html HTTP/1.1" 403 309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
```

Here's what the error_log has to say:

```
[Thu Nov 22 09:53:22 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/sales.html
```

Here's a directory listing:

```
09:55:52 myhost /var/www/html> ls -la
total 104
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root    4096 Nov 21 16:05 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root   root    4096 Nov 21 11:06 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache     6 Nov 22 09:47 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 91196 Nov 21 16:05 sales.html
```

And finally the settings in httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is really baking my noodle.  I've tried a variety of file/directory permissions, and restarted apache many times, but to no avail.  Any ideas?  Why is one file served up, but not another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't understand a lot about SELinux or security contexts, but that seems to be what's at play here.

```
12:10:24 myhost /var/www/html> ls -laZ
drwxr-xr-x. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 sales.html
```

Executing the following command seems to fix the permissions problem with Apache.

```
12:10:28 iceberg /var/www/html> sudo restorecon -r sales.html
```

And as a double-check, we can see that the security context of the misbehaving file is now different.

```
12:10:34 myhost /var/www/html> ls -laZ
drwxr-xr-x. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .
drwxr-xr-x. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 sales.html
```

Comment: this is why I HATE SELinux. It's so unbelievably stupid to implement something like that without giving applications any form of notice except "permission denied".

Comment: SELinux is not really that difficult. You do have to be more disciplined about how you handle your services and files. I'd be willing to bet that @Monkey-boson mv'd his sales.html file in from his home directory as the root user instead of copying it, which changes the destination file to the proper context.

Comment: Right. In future, `cp` files to their destination to ensure that they get the desired SELinux contexts, instead of `mv`.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the tip.  That's exactly what I did.  Unfortunate, though, that my typing is doubled (cp then rm).  I wonder if there a flag on mv to fix the context in the same way that cp does?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at what Monkey Boso says. But if it doesn't then you can try to temporarily SELinux. **Don't** do this on a production server on the public internet though, really.. **DON'T**:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

After you checked..

```
sudo setenforce 1
```

And of course don't forget to switch it back on..